# The Symfony "doctrine:fixtures:load" command is missing

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, doctrine, symfony

I have Symfony 3.1 project with Doctrine and
`doctrine/doctrine-fixtures-bundle` and
`doctrine/data-fixtures` installed.

However, when i run a console command

> php bin/console doctrine:fixtures:load

I get a message saying that there are no commands defined in the `doctrine:fixtures` namespace.

The class `Doctrine\Bundle\FixturesBundle\Command\LoadDataFixturesDoctrineCommand` exists.

Please suggest how to fix that.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Run first `php bin/console` and see if the command appear in the list.

If it doesn't, then you have to load the bundle in the `AppKernel.php`

```
$bundles[] = new Doctrine\Bundle\FixturesBundle\DoctrineFixturesBundle();
```

Comment: In my case, I made a new environment and had to add it to my bundles.php like so: `'staging' => true`

Comment: Thanks @VaelVictus you saved me.

Answer (score 3):

`php bin/console` default environment is `PROD`

and fixtures proper installation is `require-dev`

so proper function call is:

```
php bin/console --env=dev doctrine:fixtures:load
```

Answer (score 1):

Also `rm -rf var/cache` worked for me (after the bundle registration)

Answer (score 0):

Data Fixtures Mechanism requires a special bundle. It is not included in Sf by default.

Check: http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/DoctrineFixturesBundle/index.html
and install it.

Bundle called DoctrineFixturesBundle. You can also find there many useful information how to use fixtures.

So that why you've got message "Command is not defined".